# Wordpress sidebar has moved to the left of blog content (genesi)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

My sidebar area has shifted to the left side of my page - how can I put it back to the right side?

See - https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-increase-your-income-fast/

ID = genesis-sidebar-primary

Using the Genesis framework - I believe the change occurred after a recent automatic update.

Comment: Float .content to left (.content is floated right, too, as i can see).

Comment: Thanks, I need it floated right won't float: left have the opposite effect?

Comment: Both sections are float:right, not sure why - if you set .content to .left, sidebar will be placed to the right hand side. However, you could maybe remove both floats and use display:inline-block, or flex, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float your content left.

```
.content{
   float: left;
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Oh how I love a simple fix like this! Thanks :)

Comment: @SamJefferies No problem! Goodluck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

change your css
.content {float:left;}

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue when WordPress updated on two of my sites.  Once I updated to the latest version of the Genesis Framework, it was fixed.